# How can i make a custom AutocompleteTextView and keep the default layout

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to implement a autocompleteTextView that show all results if there is no search or the results that contains the search if any.

All of this with the default Ui of autocompleteTextView if possible (because i like it and i prefer to work on new features)

here what i have :

```
fun setUpIngredientTypeAutoComplete() {
    val activityContext = activity?.applicationContext
    if (activityContext != null) {
        val adapter = IngredientTypesAdapter(activityContext,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
                ingredientTypes)

        val textView = 
dialogView.findViewById<InstantAutoCompleteTextView> 
   (R.id.ingredient_type)
        textView.setAdapter<ArrayAdapter<String>>(adapter)
    }
}
```

My arrayAdapter:

```
class IngredientTypesAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int, var 
ingredientTypes: List<String>): ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, 
ingredientTypes) {

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): 
FilterResults {
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            if (constraint != null) {

                val matchingTypes = ingredientTypes.filter { type ->
                    type.contains(constraint)
                }

                filterResults.values = matchingTypes
                filterResults.count = matchingTypes.size
            }
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(contraint: CharSequence, results: 
    FilterResults?) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My custom autocompleteTextView :

```
class InstantAutoCompleteTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, 
defStyle: Int, defStyleRes: Int): AutoCompleteTextView(context, attrs, 
defStyle) {

constructor(context: Context): this(context, null, 0)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): this(context, attrs, 0)
}
```

and this is what i get:
!(https://ibb.co/4Skx1Gn)

it's not even usable...
I can't click on it, there is not edit text.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly how it's not working, and I can't see your image, but the third argument in the three-parameter constructor chain call should not be `0`. It should be `this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle)`. Btw, you can upload images here directly, by clicking [the image button above the edit box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRAP7.png).

Comment: @MikeM. You were right about android.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle.
Now I have a real input. I just have to work on the search part.

How did you know about this ? There is a documentation somewhere ?
Anyways, thank you !

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that there are any docs about that; certainly not concerning the use of that specific attribute, anyway. I just picked it up when I figured out custom `View` subclasses, from looking through the source code for various framework `View`s. Once you get the hang of it, you know what to look for. :-) Anyhoo, no problem. Glad I could help a little. Cheers!